# Warning: Editor terminated abnormally (WinHugs) (Haskell)

Tags: editor

I wannted to use another editor then the "normally" editor and so I downlowded notpad++.
Afterwards I tryed to use it in WinHugs, but there it comes the "Warning: Editor terminated abnormally".

I used File/Options/WinHugs/Editor and there I changed form "Notepad" to "Custom..." and  changed the file path to "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notpad++.exe". After trying to open the editor (":e") WinHugs striked and the Warningstuff came up.

What do I miss that it doesnt work? How can I fix it? Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have entered the correct path to Notepad++ exe in the "Custom..." field in the WinHugs options. Check this path by right-clicking on the Notepad++ shortcut and select the "Properties".

You could also try running Notepad++ as an administrator.

If you are still having trouble, you may want to try using a different text editor. I recommend checking out VS code as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks.                                                                                                                                        
In the end I didn`t really needed ur help, but nethertheless thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
Instead of using the path "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notpad++.exe" I copy pasted the folder just next to Program Files and used the path "C:\Notepad++\notpad++.exe". Afterwards it runs perfectly.

All in all next time I just try to relocaed the folders and other datas. May this help in futer problems.